# how elements from lists are chosen?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, dynamic

I am working on a java project. In that I have to calculate the highest probability from a list of lists.

Let say the list is `probs = [[0.5, 0.5, 1],[0.25,0.1,0.75]]`. probs is a list of lists, where probs[i][j] represents the probability that plant `i` will be ready in time if it is allocated `j` lamps. Values in probs are floats between 0 and 1 inclusive.

The elements in each list represent the probability that the plant will grow if we use that number of lamps, for eg. in given list if we use 0 lamps for plant0 probability is 0.5 If we use 2 lamps in plant1 probability is 0.75

Similarly if we use 10 lists with 10 elements like:

```
    probs = [[0.92, 0.88, 0.07, 0.74, 0.83, 0.73, 0.85, 0.41, 0.94, 0.58, 0.17],
             [0.05, 0.42, 0.01, 0.53, 0.03, 0.13, 0.49, 0.64, 0.13, 0.78, 0.05],
             [0.68, 0.38, 0.86, 0.6, 0.53, 0.49, 0.89, 0.18, 0.69, 0.21, 0.3],
             [0.61, 0.85, 0.17, 0.78, 0.21, 0.05, 0.09, 0.7, 0.08, 0.86, 0.21],
             [0.72, 0.81, 0.12, 0.73, 0.45, 0.8, 0.3, 0.84, 0.89, 0.48, 0.33],
             [0.19, 0.33, 0.01, 0.54, 0.71, 0.56, 0.55, 0.28, 0.29, 0.43, 0.42],
             [0.36, 0.65, 0.38, 0.48, 0.05, 0.28, 0.45, 0.42, 0.49, 0.5, 0.97],
             [0.95, 0.05, 0.73, 0.91, 0.25, 0.16, 0.11, 0.67, 0.48, 0.48, 0.77],
             [0.96, 0.21, 0.19, 0.55, 0.04, 0.58, 0.91, 0.3, 0.92, 0.36, 0.48],
             [0.46, 0.6, 0.76, 0.91, 0.79, 0.92, 0.66, 0.28, 0.48, 0.32, 0.17]]
```

In this list we have 10 plants and 10 lamps. So after calculation the result is

```
allocation of lamps to plants: [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0, 3] 
best probability: 0.061589317090129915
```

I am unable to understand how they are choosing that this prob is best for this plant. I mean what will be the judging criteria for choosing the most appropriate prob for that plant from each list depending upon the number of lamps.

What I have done for this is:

```
public static void best_lamp_allocation(int num_p, int num_l, ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>> probs) {

        List<Float> prob_Values = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> index_values = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < probs.size(); i++) {
            String value = probs.get(i).toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");

            String[] individual_values = value.split(", ");

            for (int j = 0; j < individual_values.length; j++) {
                if (Float.parseFloat(individual_values[j]) >= 0.5) {
                    prob_Values.add(Float.parseFloat(individual_values[j]));
                    index_values.add(j);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\nLamps allocated: " + index_values);

        float max_prob = 1;

        for (Float prob_value : prob_Values) {
            max_prob *= prob_value;
        }

        System.out.println("Max probability: " + max_prob);
    }
```

This code is working if the minimum prob for every plant in the 2x2 list is 0.5 but not working for other lists like for 10 x 10 list.

Comment: sorry for using that but it was recommended automatically.

Comment: Does that total number of lamps have to be exactly 10, or at most 10? This is a dynamic programming problem. You may want to see [this CS stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/108604/dynamic-programming-maximize-sum-of-functions-subject-to-constraints) post dealing with the 'maximum sum' version and adapting it.

Comment: @kcsquared number of lamps and number of plants depends upon user inputs. you cannot exceed the number of user entered lamps.

Comment: The naive approach would be to calculate all possible combinations and then use the one with the lowest propability. Other possibilieties are quite on the math heavy site

Comment: @SirHawrk like what combinations? I mean how to get these combinations. Any example plz.

Comment: The amount of lamps is just the position in the list so adding up some random positions for all xx plants would result in a random amount of lamps corresponding to that setup.

Example: [[0.5, 0.5, 1],[0.25,0.1,0.75]] You have [0.5,0.25],[0.5,0.1],[0.5,0.75],... as different combinations. The first one uses 1+1 Lamps, the 2nd one uses 1+2 lamps and the third uses 1+3 lamps. Now you discard all with #lamps > #allowedLamps, Calculate the average propability for each and then use the lowest.

Comment: @SirHawrk Since this is a standard DP problem, possibly assigned as homework, I would not recommend using an exponential time algorithm. Following the template given in the linked question with only minor changes gives a simple O(n^3) time algorithm.

Comment: @kcsquared  it should run in O(PL2) time and O(PL) space where p represents the no. of plants and L represents the number of lamps.

Comment: @kcsquared definetly not. I would never advise anyone to actually use exponential time but OP imo seemed to be lacking any sort of understanding about the exercise so I tried to explain it as simply as I could

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose `results` is a 2D table and `results[i][j]` is highest probability for `i` plants and at most `j` lamps. you can easily fill `results[0][j]` and `results[i][0]`. for `results[i][j]` such that `i, j > 0` you can fill it based on previous row i.e. `results[i-1][0 to j]` and previous cell `results[i][j-1]`

1. when we want to fill `results[i][j]` one case is to look into
   previous row , I have highest probability and the number of lamps
   used to get that probability for each cell, we used these
   information to get how many lamps I can use for the current plant and compute its probability if we use that many lamps then choose the highest probability,
   it is candidate `m1`.
2. another case is to ignore the added lamp and just use the
   `results[i][j-1]` probability and lamps. it is `m2`.

the max between these 2 numbers is the value for `results[i][j]`

code:

```
 static int argmax(double[] arr, int i, int j) {
    double max = arr[0];
    int re = 0;
    for (int t = i; t < j + 1; t++) {
      if (arr[t] > max) {
        max = arr[t];
        re = t;
      }
    }
    return re;
  }

  static double maxBetweenRange(double[] arr, int i, int j) {
    double max = arr[i];
    for (int t = i + 1; t <= j; t++) {
      if (arr[t] > max) {
        max = arr[t];
      }
    }
    return max;
  }

  public static Unit max(Unit... num) {
    double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    Unit res = null;
    for (Unit v : num) {
      if (v.prob > max) {
        max = v.prob;
        res = v;
      }
    }
    return res;
  }


  public static class Unit {

    public double prob;
    public int lamp;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Unit{" +
          "prob=" + prob +
          ", lamp=" + lamp +
          '}';
    }
  }




public static Unit[][] getHighProb(double[][] probs, int userLamps) {
    Unit[][] results = new Unit[probs.length][Math.min(userLamps + 1, probs[0].length)];
    for (int j = 0; j < results[0].length; j++) {
      Unit u = new Unit();
      u.prob = maxBetweenRange(probs[0], 0, j);
      u.lamp = argmax(probs[0], 0, j);
      results[0][j] = u;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < results.length; i++) {
      Unit u = new Unit();
      u.prob = results[i - 1][0].prob * probs[i][0];
      u.lamp = 0;
      results[i][0] = u;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < results.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 1; j < results[0].length; j++) {
        Unit current;
        Unit[] beforeRow = results[i - 1];
        Unit m1 = new Unit();
        m1.prob = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        m1.lamp = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int k = j; k > 0; k--) {
          Unit x = beforeRow[k];
          int remainingLamps = j - x.lamp;
          for (int l = 0; l <= remainingLamps; l++) {
            if (x.prob * probs[i][l] > m1.prob) {
              m1.prob = x.prob * probs[i][l];
              m1.lamp = l + x.lamp;
            }
          }
        }


        Unit m2 = new Unit();
        m2.prob = results[i][j - 1].prob;
        m2.lamp = results[i][j - 1].lamp;

        current = max(m1, m2);
        results[i][j] = current;
      }
    }
    return results;
  }
```

call it like:

```
Unit[][] array = getHighProb(probs, 10);
```

you can easily find the highest probability for `i` plants and `j` lamps. time complexity is `O(PL^2)`(#plants, #lamps). for `10` plants and `10` lamps you have this:

`array[9][10]= Unit{prob=0.061589317090129915, lamp=10}`